# Summing a list by one property after filtering by another property

Tags: c#, .net, linq, where-clause

I have a class:

```
class Cars 
{
   String Part;
   int NrOfParts;
}
```

and a `List<Cars>`.

I would like to get the `sum` of `NrOfParts` for a specific `Part` using lambda expressions.

I would like something like this:

```
 double sum = sil.Sum(item => item.NrOfParts WHERE item.Part == SomePart);
```

where `sil` is my list and `SomePart` is specific part I'm looking for.

The problem is that I don't know how to add a `where` condition to restrict the search for a specific case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the where clause first (using the where method), and then you sum over the filtered list.

```
double sum = sil.Where(i => i.Part == SomePart).Sum(i => i.NrOfParts);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
  double sum = sil.Where(item => item.Part == SomePart).Sum(item => item.NrOfParts);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this: -

```
double sum = Convert.ToDouble(sil.Where(item => item.Part == SomePart).Sum(item => item.NrOfParts));
```

Comment: Sum will return an int (since `NrOfParts` is an int) and you don't need to use Convert.ToDouble to go from an int to a double.

Answer (score -1):

```
       //Your range will come here
        IEnumerable<double> d=Enumerable.Range(2.67,100);
       // Your condition
       d.Where(d1 => d1 % 2.0 == 0).CumulativeSum();

 public static class Extension

    {
        public static IEnumerable<double> CumulativeSum(this IEnumerable<double> sequence)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            foreach (var item in sequence)
            {
                sum += item;
                yield return sum;
            }
        }

    }
```